# Regex String to Date

Tags: regex

I would like to change "05092016" to "05/09/2016" using regex. Any suggestions?

Comment: What flavor are you using?

Comment: `2digits2digits4digits` => `2d/2d/4d`. Regex: `(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})` ==> `$1/$2/$3`. Don't even need regex if using string methods.

Comment: The best suggestion would be to pick up a book or read an online tutorial, as this will actually teach you something, rather than give you something to copy/paste and be on your way. This is pretty basic stuff you should be able to get done with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very simple. Use this pattern:

```
/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/
```

And replace it with `$1/$2/$3`

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW6qU9/2)

Comment: Why `\\\` in replacement part? should be `/`.

Comment: @Tushar What? I'm not sure what's your point. You can see demo which is linked in the answer.

Comment: For example, in Ruby: `"05092016".gsub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '\1/\2/\3')`

Comment: @Shafizadeh The point is that you're using \ instead of /, so you're actually using a backslash.